# mysql query taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query that is taking way too long to execute (4 seconds) even though all the fields i am querying against are indexed. Below are the query and the explain results. Any ideas what the problem is? (mysql CPU usage shoots up to 100% when executing the query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(hd.did) as NumPo, `hd`.`sid`, `src`.`Name`
FROM (`hd`)
JOIN `result` ON `result`.`did` = `hd`.`did`
JOIN `sf` ON `sf`.`fid` = `hd`.`fid`
JOIN `src` ON `src`.`sid` = `hd`.`sid`
WHERE `sf`.`tid` =  2
AND `result`.`set` =  'xxxxxxx'
GROUP BY `hd`.`sid`
ORDER BY `NumPo` DESC
LIMIT 10;

+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys           | key     | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sf           | ref    | PRIMARY,type            | type    | 2       | const                    |    4 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | hd           | ref    | PRIMARY,sid,fid         | FeedID  | 4       | f2.sf.fid                |    3 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | result       | ALL    | resultset               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | 5322 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | src          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY | 4       | f2.hd.sid                |    1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What kind of join does just `JOIN` do?

Comment: Please post TEXT output of SHOW CREATE TABLE result;   You appear to be missing an index on the column named set in the result table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
|  1 | SIMPLE      | result       | ALL    | resultset               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | 5322 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
```

It looks like it's not using an index on the biggest table. I'm having trouble guessing what this query is supposed to do, but it looks like you have an index on `result.set`, so I'd try adding one to `result.did` and see if it helps.