# Why MYSQL is taking too long to run first query?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I am using (MYSQL Workbench 8.0).
When I execute the first query (simple select query). It takes too long (1 minute 15 seconds on average) to execute that query. After the first successful attempt, it works fine.

**Additional Info:**
My database is on AWS (Amazon Web Services) and it is a private database.

Simple Query like:

> SELECT * FROM DATABASE_TABLE LIMIT 1;

I read other sources but unable to find the right answer.

**Additional Resources:**

[mysql query taking too long to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381267/mysql-query-taking-too-long-to-execute)

[Amazon RDS MySQL instance performs very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035958/amazon-rds-mysql-instance-performs-very-slow)
[MySQL query is the very slow first time to run](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=816634&tstart=0)

Comment: First time to run query has many 'one-time' housekeeping duties to complete the first query.  What are you calling too long?  2 seconds or 20 seconds?  How many tables are available to the instance?  How many indexes are available to the instance? Each one takes time.